# Spirit X3: Custom number parser yield unexpected leading zero in the result

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I'm writing a long number parser, which identify a valid number (maybe not representable in builtin integer type) and store the string as-is. But the result included an unexpected leading '0'.

The parser simply identify numbers in the form like `0xHHHHHH`, `ObBBBBBBB`, `0OOOOOOO` or `DDDDDDDDD`

To preserve the number prefix in the result, I use `x3::string` rather than `x3::lit`, the former parser has an attribute of `String` while the latter is `unused`

Here is the link to the code https://wandbox.org/permlink/E8mOpCcH3Svqb3FJ

And the same code in case the link expired.

```cpp
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
namespace fusion = boost::fusion;

using x3::_val;
using x3::_attr;
using x3::_where;
using fusion::at_c;

x3::rule<struct LongHexInt, std::string> const long_hex_int = "long_hex_int";

auto const long_hex_int_def = x3::lexeme[
    (x3::string("0") >> +x3::char_('0', '7'))
    | ((x3::digit - '0') >> *x3::digit >> 'u')
    | ((x3::string("0x") | x3::string("0X")) >> +x3::xdigit)
    | ((x3::string("0b") | x3::string("0B")) >> +x3::char_('0', '1'))
];

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(long_hex_int);

int main() {
    std::string input = R"__(0x12345678ABCDEF)__";
    std::string output;
    if (x3::parse(input.begin(), input.end(), long_hex_int, output)) {
        std::cout << output;
    }
}
```

As it's shown in the result, the parser `output` is `00x12345678ABCDEF` not `0x12345678ABCDEF`, I don't know where the additional '0' come from.

After removing the alternation in line 15 (`(x3::string("0") >> +x3::char_('0', '7'))`), the code produced expected output. But I don't know why, is it a bug or my fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd personally simplify. The common part of the number format could be written as:

```
auto const common 
    = x3::no_case["0x"] >> x3::hex
    | x3::no_case["0b"] >> x3::bin
    | &x3::lit('0') >> x3::oct
    | x3::uint_ >> 'u'
    ;
```

This uses the builtin unsigned parsers from https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/numeric/uint.html

Now you could parse that into the string representation:

```
auto const long_hex_int
    = x3::rule<struct long_hex_int_, std::string> {"long_hex_int"}
    = x3::lexeme [ x3::raw [ common ] ];
```

But you could just as easily parse directly into the integral type:

```
auto const unsigned_literal
    = x3::rule<struct unsigned_literal_, uint32_t> {"unsigned_literal"}
    = x3::lexeme [ common ];
```

In fact here is a live demo with test cases:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a31f9cd5879f526)</kbd>**

```
for (std::string const input : { 
    "0",
    "00",
    "010",
    "0x0", "0b0", "0x10", "0b10", "0x010", "0b010",
    "0X0", "0B0", "0X10", "0B10", "0X010", "0B010",
    // fails:
    "", "0x", "0b", "0x12345678ABCDEF" })
{
    std::string str;
    uint32_t num;
    if (x3::parse(input.begin(), input.end(), long_hex_int >> x3::eoi, str)) {
        std::cout << std::quoted(input) << " -> " << std::quoted(str) << "\n";
        if (x3::parse(input.begin(), input.end(), unsigned_literal, num)) {
            std::cout << " numerical: " << std::hex << "0x" << num << " (" << std::dec << num << ")\n";
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << std::quoted(input) << " -> FAILED\n";
    }
}
```

Printing:

```
"0" -> "0"
 numerical: 0x0 (0)
"00" -> "00"
 numerical: 0x0 (0)
"010" -> "010"
 numerical: 0x8 (8)
"0x0" -> "0x0"
 numerical: 0x0 (0)
"0b0" -> "0b0"
 numerical: 0x0 (0)
"0x10" -> "0x10"
 numerical: 0x10 (16)
"0b10" -> "0b10"
 numerical: 0x2 (2)
"0x010" -> "0x010"
 numerical: 0x10 (16)
"0b010" -> "0b010"
 numerical: 0x2 (2)
"0X0" -> "0X0"
 numerical: 0x0 (0)
"0B0" -> "0B0"
 numerical: 0x0 (0)
"0X10" -> "0X10"
 numerical: 0x10 (16)
"0B10" -> "0B10"
 numerical: 0x2 (2)
"0X010" -> "0X010"
 numerical: 0x10 (16)
"0B010" -> "0B010"
 numerical: 0x2 (2)
"" -> FAILED
"0x" -> FAILED
"0b" -> FAILED
"0x12345678ABCDEF" -> FAILED
```

### Extending for 64 bits

Extending for more precision should make more succeed, right?

It gets only slightly more annoying to write:

```
template <typename T = uint64_t>
auto const common 
    = x3::no_case["0x"] >> x3::uint_parser<T, 16>{}
    | x3::no_case["0b"] >> x3::uint_parser<T, 2>{}
    | &x3::lit('0')     >> x3::uint_parser<T, 8>{}
    | x3::uint_parser<T, 10>{} >> 'u'
    ;
```

But all the rest is the same, and your 64 bit example passes:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/118fb3dd5bd71a21)</kbd>**

```
"0x12345678ABCDEF" -> 0x12345678abcdef (5124095577148911)
```

But `131!` fails to parse, for obvious reasons:

```
"847158069087882051098456875815279568163352087665474498775849754305766436915303927682164623187034167333264599970492141556534816949699515865660644961729169613882287309922474300878212776434073600000000000000000000000000000000" -> FAILED
```

### Bonus: Arbitrary precision

131! requires around log₂(131!) ≅ 737 bits... But you don't need to fall back to lugging around strings. Just drop in `uint1024_t` (or `checked_uint1024_t`) from Boost Multiprecision and your'e done:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cdc41b7037dfb58b)</kbd>**

```
using Number = boost::multiprecision::/*checked_*/uint1024_t;
```

And then

```
Number num;
if (x3::parse(input.begin(), input.end(), unsigned_literal<Number> >> x3::eoi, num)) {
    std::cout << std::quoted(input) << " -> " << std::hex << "0x" << num << " (" << std::dec << num << ")\n";
} else {
    std::cout << std::quoted(input) << " -> FAILED\n";
}
```

Note how nothing changed except `uint64_t` -> `Number`. And the output:

```
"0" -> 0x0 (0)
"00" -> 0x0 (0)
"010" -> 0x8 (8)
"0x0" -> 0x0 (0)
"0b0" -> 0x0 (0)
"0x10" -> 0x10 (16)
"0b10" -> 0x2 (2)
"0x010" -> 0x10 (16)
"0b010" -> 0x2 (2)
"0X0" -> 0x0 (0)
"0B0" -> 0x0 (0)
"0X10" -> 0x10 (16)
"0B10" -> 0x2 (2)
"0X010" -> 0x10 (16)
"0B010" -> 0x2 (2)
"0x12345678ABCDEF" -> 0x12345678ABCDEF (5124095577148911)
"847158069087882051098456875815279568163352087665474498775849754305766436915303927682164623187034167333264599970492141556534816949699515865660644961729169613882287309922474300878212776434073600000000000000000000000000000000u" -> 0x257F7A37BE2FBDD9980A97214F27DDC1E2FFA53ABBA836FFBE8AD1B9792E5D47A3C573A1B9C81D264662E41005A5D7432ADDBE44E3DDF12142D2B845FC9B184288345AD466B86A6685FE87AE100000000000000000000000000000000 (847158069087882051098456875815279568163352087665474498775849754305766436915303927682164623187034167333264599970492141556534816949699515865660644961729169613882287309922474300878212776434073600000000000000000000000000000000)
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because a failure in one of the alternatives does not cause rollback in the attribute. To force the rollback, make them separate rules, [like this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eExHR5jaTLDZzmJo):

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
namespace fusion = boost::fusion;

using x3::_val;
using x3::_attr;
using x3::_where;
using x3::rule;
using fusion::at_c;

x3::rule<struct LongHexInt, std::string> const long_hex_int = "long_hex_int";

template <typename T> 
auto as = [](auto p) { 
   return rule<struct _, T> {} = p; 
};

auto const long_hex_int_def = 
    x3::lexeme[as<std::string>(x3::string("0") >> +x3::char_('0', '7')) 
    | as<std::string>((x3::digit - '0') >> *x3::digit >> 'u')
    | as<std::string>((x3::string("0x") | x3::string("0X")) >> +x3::xdigit)
    | as<std::string>((x3::string("0b") | x3::string("0B")) >> +x3::char_('0', '1'))]
;

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(long_hex_int);

int main() {
    std::string input = R"__(0x12345678ABCDEF)__";
    std::string output;
    if (x3::parse(input.begin(), input.end(), long_hex_int, output)) {
        std::cout << output;
    }
}
```

(It seems not to be working in Boost 1.70! Maybe a bug?)

Comment: Thanks a lot, wil try that later, and also thanks for the `as` parser.

Comment: Tried, produced same result, ummmmm

Comment: @user9386515 as for `as` helper, all credits go to @sehe  :-)

Comment: @user9386515 Did you try my link to wandbox?

Comment: Tried, I'm currently using boost 1.70, still wrong result.

Comment: @user9386515  That's what I wrote: the solution does not work in 1.70, it looks like a bug in 1.70.

Comment: After some quick debugging, I found that the attribute is all the way passed 
throgh by reference from the `parse` function in main to the actual parser, and there is no any rollback code. It also reminds me of the change in x3 since boost 1.70 that eliminates some 'unnecessary' copy of attributes. That may be the real problem here. Which is also the reason I use boost 1.70 - I need `unique_ptr` as attribute, which disabled copy.

Comment: @user9386515 In the meanwhile I filed [an issue](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/issues/527), lets see what they say.

Comment: @IgorR. thanks for that hat tip :) I'd say `x3::raw` is the more natural fit to parse the string representation here (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

After trying @IgorR.'s code and some debugging, I found that Spirit X3 removed some attribute copy since boost 1.70, so when parsing with mutable container object, auto rollback is no longer available because you need a copy of attribute to do that.

So boost spirit introduced an attribute transform machanism, It's called before and after pasing a rule, the default implementation is just return the refernce, so customize attribute transform behaviour for std::string's to make a copy will solve the problem. Basically you need to spicialize a struct like:

@user1681377 pointed out that there is unnecessary copy of attribute in the code below, It is now edited with only move operation, still has overhead, but way less.

```cpp
template<>
struct boost::spirit::x3::default_transform_attribute<std::string, std::string> {
    typedef std::string type;
    static std::string pre(std::string& val) { return std::move(val); }
    static void post(std::string& old_val, std::string&& new_val) {
        old_val = std::move(new_val);
    }
};
```

Then the problem is solved. see https://wandbox.org/permlink/MLYLbSeXBBjDqATN

BTW. @sehe thought hacking implementation is not a good idea, I agree, but for current situation, maybe it's the simplest way to do that? And I doubt this `transform_attribute` is a customization point?

Comment: Oh, BTW I found the std::move is useless, move from const is copy

Comment: I would argue that depending on archaics like this is not a solid approach. I provided a much simplied parser for inspiration in my answer.

Comment: Also, @user9386515, if you put print statements in your transform, you'll see it makes apparently redundant copies.  That's just one more reason to adopt sehe's solution.

Comment: @sehe I doubt `x3::traits::transform_attribute` is a customization point?

Comment: It was in Qi. Not to sure about the customization points in X3. Frankly, I haven't needed the customizations since the whole generator system is so much more flexible anyways now. I've overloaded/specialized a `move_to` function once. I think.

Comment: (Maybe deriving from `x3::parser_base` was approaching customization, but again it's just a much simpler way to define custom parsers.)